# How to set image as featured via ajax in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I need to set an image as featured in Wordpress via ajax call. So i did this function:

```
   function FeaturedImage() {
    $image_ID = $_POST['thumbnail_id'];
    $post_ID =  $_POST['post_id'];
    check_ajax_referer( 'savemediaimage', 'nonce' );
    update_post_meta( $post_ID, '_thumbnail_id', $image_ID );
    }
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_postthumbnail',        'FeaturedImage' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_postthumbnail', 'FeaturedImage');
```

And this is the ajax call:

```
jQuery.post(ajaxparam.ajax_url, {
    nonce: ajaxparam.nonce,
    post_id : '924',
    thumbnail_id : '887',
    action: 'postthumbnail'
    });
```

In the console log, post content is:

```
nonce=7bb3cb3f9d&post_id=924&thumbnail_id=887&action=postthumbnail
```

answer:

```
200 OK
```

but never image is sets as featured.
I also tried to use `set_post_thumbnail` instead of `update_post_meta` without success.
What is wrong? Thanks

Comment: did you try with `jQuery.ajax({               type:'POST',`?

Comment: I tried to use jQuery.ajax and i get the same correct post string and success answer in console log. But no image is sets as featured.

Comment: did you print `$image_ID` this  value and check in console?

Comment: Yes, it is printed. I also tried to specify parameters directly in `update_post_meta( '924', '_thumbnail_id', '887' );` but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Its working

```
function postthumbnail() {
    echo $image_ID = $_POST['thumbnail_id'];
    $post_ID =  $_POST['post_id'];
    //check_ajax_referer( 'savemediaimage', 'nonce' );
    update_post_meta( $post_ID, '_thumbnail_id', $image_ID );
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_postthumbnail','postthumbnail' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_postthumbnail', 'postthumbnail'); 





<input type="button" id="test">


<script>
    jQuery(document).on("click","#test",function(){
      jQuery.ajax({
          type:    "POST",
          url:     ajaxparam.ajax_url,
          data:    {post_id : '9',thumbnail_id : '2850', action: 'postthumbnail', },     
          success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
                alert('call back');
          }
        });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for help but unfortunately not work to my side. No `_thumbnail_id` post meta are created or updated in database.

Comment: It's working for me. You are trying with existing Thumnail id?

Comment: Update. I now discovered that `_thumbnail_id` is update in db but no images appears in the featured metabox. So if a update the post _thumbnail_id is replaced and deleted.

Comment: Problem now is how update the featured metabox after retrive the new update_post_meta

Comment: you will get thumnail url  and append in your html

Comment: How can i refresh the wp featured image box so to catch the updated post_meta and show the new featured image inside it?

[link](http://cdn2.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/featuerd-image-wordpress.png)

Comment: Yes, on edit mode i run a tinymce dialog and submit it to add shortcode and set new featured image.

Comment: replace the image url on ajax success method

Comment: wp featured image box, if empty, hasn't any element id inside but olny a link to media library.

Comment: the create a html like featured box html and append or reload the page